why is my gcc.exe red and wont let my code run?
so out of no where my code wont run. i dont know if its the compiler or something. but i get either 0 problems or expected primary-expression before ´;´ token. and. expected an expression. in my terminal c/c++:gcc.exe build active file is red. please help
my code
#include <iostream>
using namespace std:

int main(){
cout<<"hello"<<endl;
return 0

i was trying to build a little project like bmi calculatior. but i was getting frustred becuse i couldt run my code. so i ereased everything and wrote the little code i think must run without problems.

You have not closed your bracket at the end }
